# `apt install pkg1 pkg2` differs from `apt install pkg1 && apt install pkg2` why?

Tags: apt

If I install both packages at the same time I get this, note that php7.4 would be installed:

```
$ apt install php7.1 php7.1-redis

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils ifupdown iproute2 isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common libapache2-mod-php7.1 libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libargon2-0 libatm1 libbsd0 libdns-export162 libedit2
  libgdbm3 libisc-export160 liblua5.1-0 libmnl0 libpcre2-8-0 libperl5.22 libsodium23 libssl1.1 libxtables11 netbase perl perl-modules-5.22 php-common php-igbinary php-redis php7.1 php7.1-cli php7.1-common php7.1-json php7.1-opcache
  php7.1-readline php7.4-cli php7.4-common php7.4-json php7.4-opcache php7.4-phpdbg php7.4-readline psmisc rename ssl-cert tzdata
```

If I install them separately, php7.4 doesn't get installed:

```
$ apt install php7.1

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils ifupdown iproute2 isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common libapache2-mod-php7.1 libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libatm1 libbsd0 libdns-export162 libedit2 libgdbm3
  libisc-export160 liblua5.1-0 libmnl0 libperl5.22 libssl1.1 libxtables11 netbase perl perl-modules-5.22 php-common php7.1 php7.1-cli php7.1-common php7.1-json php7.1-opcache php7.1-readline psmisc rename ssl-cert tzdata

$ apt install php7.1-redis

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php-igbinary php-redis
```

Why? I'm not totally new to linux but I've never noticed this behaviour.

To try it you can use docker:

```
docker run -it --rm ubuntu:16.04 bash
```

Those packages require an additional ppa, so:

```
apt update && apt install -y software-properties-common
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php && apt-get update
```

And you're ready to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt` outputs an easy-to-miss message which gives a hint:

> Note, selecting 'php-redis' instead of 'php7.1-redis'

`php7.1-redis` doesn’t exist, or rather, it’s a virtual package provided by `php-redis`. So `apt` changes

```
apt install php7.1 php7.1-redis
```

to

```
apt install php7.1 php-redis
```

When both packages are requested simultaneously, `apt` considers all their dependencies, and in this scenario gets tripped up by its virtual alternatives handling. `php-redis` depends on `phpapi-20190902 | phpapi-20180731 | phpapi-20170718 | phpapi-20160303 | phpapi-20151012 | phpapi-20131226`, which are provided by a number of concrete PHP packages; `apt` picks `php7.4-cli`, which is the first package in the order of evaluation to satisfy the dependency. It also resolves `php7.1`, but probably because the `phpapi` connection is different (PHP 7.4 provides `phpapi-20190902`, PHP 7.1 provides `phpapi-20160303`), doesn’t realise that `php7.1` ends up satisfying `php-redis`’ dependencies.

When `php-redis` is installed after `php7.1`, the `phpapi` requirements are already satisfied, so `apt` doesn’t try to install anything more.

Comment: Ah... I see, it makes perfect sense. And now I'm scared to install multiple packages at the same time.